# date queries in phoenix sql?

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

How do you select observations recorded in between now and 3 hrs ago i.e. now-3?
There is a column which has timestamp and I am referring to that column in this question. I know phoenix has function [current_time()](http://forcedotcom.github.io/phoenix/functions.html#current_time) which can give us the current time but how can I subtract 3 hrs from it?

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from table 
where col1 between current_time() and ???;
```

What should I use at `???` ?

Comment: In a standard-compliant SQL implementation, it would be `SELECT current_time() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix does not support interval data types. 
https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html

You should subtract a number which either represents a number of days (use fractional days) or milliseconds. I don't remember which it was though.